# can not create facebook test page using test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Trying to create "test facebook page" after login using "test user" gives error:

```
"This content is no longer available"
```

screenshot: 
[image]

I tried to give my test user "admin role" in my existing page but that does not seem to work, thus trying to create "test page" manually using "test user" gives me this error.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure this is exactly your issue, but there are currently two open bugs about creating Pages with Test Users:

- https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/983667641797373/
- https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2156602097896238/

Meanwhile, you might be able to use the Graph API to create the page, as suggested by a comment. You can see the request in the Graph Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v3.0&name=Bob%20Test%20Page%201&category=756092301147942&about=Bob%20test&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fbowwowinsurance.com.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F12%2Ffrench-bulldog-frenchie-700x700.jpg&cover_photo=%7B%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fbowwowinsurance.com.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F12%2Ffrench-bulldog-frenchie-700x700.jpg%22%7D

Comment: Note that when opening Graph API explorer, by default you'll be using the token with whatever account you're currently logged in as! For creating Test Pages, grab the token from the Test Users located in App Dashboard --> Role --> Test Users (pick test user) --> Edit --> Get access token

Answer (score 0):

I just created a page with a test account and it worked.

You have to connect to the account, and click here from the test user profile :
[image]

or you can follow this link : https://www.facebook.com/pages/creation/

**UPDATE (AUGUST 2018)**

It seems to work only with test users created from this url : [www.facebook.com/whitehat/accounts/](https://www.facebook.com/whitehat/accounts/). These users are linked to a real profile, not to a Facebook App.

Comment: This page does not function at present. See: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/983667641797373/